# Misbehaving irssi Pagination in tmux

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tmux, tty, buffer

I'm experiencing some strange console pagination behaviour in tmux when SSH'd to a Ubuntu host (EC2 instance on AWS). I've demonstrated this behaviour by running irssi inside the tmux and hitting <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

(I'm aware that normally one should hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to go up through buffer pages in tmux, but this should work in irssi as it's a terminal application that takes over the buffer and the paging.)

[image: strange console pagination behaviour]

You can see that it seems to think the window/buffer is about half of its actual size and move it to the top or bottom of the actual space, if that makes sense.

My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`, `$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`, `tty` is `/dev/pts/2` (for the moment at least, the pts number changes I think).

`tmux -V` is now 2.3 as I've tried installing the latest master from source, I first experienced this behaviour with the tmux that is packaged in the regular Ubuntu repositories (which was version 2.1). My Ubuntu is 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: What do `stty size` and `echo $LINES $COLUMNS` print in your shell (before starting up irssi)? Do those numbers match the actual window size? Try these both before and after starting tmux.

Comment: @egmont Yes it's 55 191 before starting tmux and then 54 191 after starting tmux (presumably due to the status bar line at the bottom)

Comment: Don't you need `TERM=screen` inside tmux?

Comment: If you do that, your colors may not work (e.g., only 16 colors).  tmux would work with `screen-256color` about as well as your non-tmux `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, `tmux` relies upon using the terminal capabilities in the `screen` terminal description.  Besides function-keys (which `tmux` does in a different way), here are a few of the differences which affect cursor movement (all features in xterm but not in screen), which you could see using `infocmp xterm-256color screen`:

```
    hpa: '\E[%i%p1%dG', NULL.
    indn: '\E[%p1%dS', NULL.
    rin: '\E[%p1%dT', NULL.
    vpa: '\E[%i%p1%dd', NULL.
```

If you set [`TERM=screen`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen), that tells most applications to use only the number of colors described therein (8). tmux would work with [`screen-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen-256color) about as well as your non-tmux xterm-256color

There also are [`tmux` and `tmux-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-tmux) entries, but it is common for packagers to provide by default only a cut-down terminal database without these.  You might want to install the `ncurses-term` package as a start.

Answer (score 0):

As meuh commented, `TERM=screen` was needed when in a tmux session.

Comment: Can you edit this answer please, so you can earn reputation for answering your own question?  I'll leave this for now.